# PYTHON Парсинг c Beautiful Soup Ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Код на сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код:

```
url = 'https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=https:%2F%2F' + message.text
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, url, parse_mode='html')
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find_all('p', class_='ng-star-inserted')

print(quotes)
```

Почемуто выводит:

```
[]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Выведите `response.text` и убедитесь, что тот тег там есть, т.к. возможно он появляется после выполнения какого-либо javascript на сайте

Comment: Еще есть такой вариант, что сайт фильтрует User-Agent и если видит в заголовках requests, может не возвращать ожидаемого ответа.

Comment: Изменил сайт на:
https://opentip.kaspersky.com/
Я не понимаю помогите пж

Comment: на  opentip.kaspersky.com вы тоже ищете 'p', class_='ng-star-inserted'?